# Getting links from Website with Python (Beginner)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to using beautifulsoup4 to scrape the ínformation embedded within items of the "products product-grid" div section. I tried now several hours to mine the links within these a objects as shown here:

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjFR3.jpg)

My code is pretty simple but my "productlist" empty. Does anyone have a good guess of why I cannot access my links and prices of the items in the grid? - Any help is much appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

baseurl = "https://www.xl-byg.dk/"

k = requests.get('https://www.xl-byg.dk/produkter/trae-byggematerialer/gulve/laminatgulve')
soup=BeautifulSoup(k.content,'html.parser')
productlist = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"products product-grid"})
print(productlist)

productlinks = []
for product in productlist:
        link = product.find("a",{"class":"reset-style"}).get('href')                 
        productlinks.append(baseurl + link)
```

Comment: try `soup=BeautifulSoup(k.content,'html.parser')` instead of `soup=BeautifulSoup(k,'html.parser')`

Comment: @GhostOps That is a good point, but there is second thing, site serves content dynamically via javascript 

awi1100: please take a look in your soup first.

Comment: What would I look for in the soup? with having .content helped and was needed, but the productlist is still empty...

Comment: So take a closer look, I still gave you a hint what happens.

Comment: Ok so I do not find the div and class name "products product-grid" there, do you have another hint?

Comment: As mentioned, content is served dynamically and `requests` do not render the result like a browser would do. You have to find an api or use [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: `https://www.xl-byg.dk/search/resources/store/10201/productview/byCategory/3074457345616703457?searchSource=E&searchType=10&pageSize=24&pageNumber=1&checkEntitlement=true&priceMode=calculated&_wcf.search.contract=-10001&langId=-100&catalogId=11601&currency=DKK`